# Converting 0x1 to 1 in java

Tags: java, hex, decimal

0x1 is the hexadecimal form of 1. More information is in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904219/what-does-return-0x1-mean).
I'm trying to convert that `0x1` into `1`. So I'm using this code.

```
    String hex = "0x1";
    int decimal = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    System.out.println(decimal);
```

However, it returns exception as

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x1"
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
> at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:7)

How can I make this `java` code print 1?

Comment: You could skip the first two characters. `int decimal = Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(2), 16);`

Comment: Yep, this also works... thanks, mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Integer.decode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode-java.lang.String-):

```
String hex = "0x1";
int value = Integer.decode(hex);
System.out.println(value);
```

(Note: I've renamed the integer variable from 'decimal' to 'value', since there's nothing specifically decimal about it; it's just an integer. It's actually represented as binary internally.)